# Don't you heard OR haven't you heard

Tags: indian-english

I am asking about a place from someone that you know this place or not.

So what is the correct line?

```
don't you heard about that place
```

**OR**

```
haven't you heard about that place
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you heard about that place?

Don't you get news from John any more ?

'have' is used with the past participle of 'hear'. (Present Perfect)
The time period is your life - like saying: Haven't you ever heard of that place?

'don't' is used with the infinitive. (Simple Present)
(for a present truth)

Comment: Thanks for the answer...could be explain it? i would be very helpful

Comment: @GauravAggarwal  See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two correct ways:

Didn't you hear about the place? (Past tense)

Haven't you heard about the place? (Present perfect).